# Field Extension example

Tags: extension-field

Find the degree extension of $$[Q(\theta, \phi ) :Q]$$ where $$[Q(\theta) :Q]=5$$ and $$[Q(\phi ) :Q]=2$$.

This is what I have $$[Q(\theta, \phi ) :Q]\times[Q(\phi ) :Q]= (5-2)(2) = 6$$. Is this right?

Comment: No, $[\mathbb Q(\theta, \phi ) :\mathbb Q(\phi)]\times[\mathbb Q(\phi ) :\mathbb Q]= 5\times2 = 10$.

Comment: why is  [Q(θ,ϕ):Q(ϕ)] equal to 5?

Comment: $[Q(\theta,\phi):Q]=[Q(\theta,\phi):Q(\phi)][Q(\phi):Q]=[Q(\theta,\phi):Q(\theta)][Q(\theta):Q]$